# Remotely restart Windows VM - get status?

Tags: windows

I use the following command to execute routine restarts of Windows 10 VMs:

```
shutdown /m <server> /r
```

For some VMs it takes quite some time before they are available again. Is there a command to check the status of the VM? If it is a) still shutting down, b) already starting again, c) installing Windows updates or d) up & running again?

Comment: You could set up an ongoing ping with `-t`, but as far as I know that's the most you can get without access to the console. If it's a server, then all you need is access to an ILO system or VM management console to see the status. Do you have either of those?

Comment: If you are on the Hyper-V host: `get-vm <name> | ft` or `get-vm <name> | fl` or `get-vm <name> | select -property *`.

Comment: eh...or just use `get-vm -computername <hyper-v-host>`

Comment: If the VM is up, I've found `pslist` to be very useful in distinguishing between "still shutting down" and "up and running".  You can also usually see if updates are installing by using the `-s` option though that isn't quite as clear-cut.  Available from Microsoft's web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it, but if I remember right,

- if you use cmd/batch with remote commands I'm not sure you will have a very reliable way of working
- if you use use powershell and/or pstools you will be able to have a few informations about what your computer is doing by requesting the registry base, I remember I did it when I had to control available updates on remote VMs and to reboot it but I'm not sure you will have the state of your VM in real time. You can still ping or try a connection to the registry base if you want to test if the VM is started
- probably the most reliable if you can do it, request your hypervisor to get the state of your VM

Here is an example for this last scenario on VMWare using Powercli : https://code.vmware.com/forums/2530/vsphere-powercli#591783

And of course you still can do it using the VMWare REST API.

And actually I strongly invite you to search into the registry base, there are ways of seeing the state of updates on your computer (to be installed, failed, installation in progress etc...)